# Jstree : Create node with custom div

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jstree

I use the plugin Jstree to manage my menu dynamically.

I have custom my tree with some div to display icons and links :

```
<li rel="menu">
  <a class="js_menu_titre">
          <p class="jsmenu_titre_taille">Menu_Principal</p>
          <div class="jsmenu_lien">Link</div>
          <p class="jsmenu_icone">Actif : icon</p>
          <p class="jsmenu_action">Actions : icon_action</p>
  </a>
```

my problem is that when I want to use the function create node, I don't have my divs anymore. My customs divs are inside the link ()

You can see the result and the problem here : http://i71.servimg.com/u/f71/11/07/15/68/arbo10.jpg

I use this function :

```
$("#jsmenu").bind("create.jstree", function (e, data) {
$.post(
    "/static/v.1.0pre/_demo/server.php", 
    { 
        "operation" : "create_node", 
        "id" : data.rslt.parent.attr("id").replace("node_",""), 
        "position" : data.rslt.position,
        "title" : data.rslt.name,
        "type" : data.rslt.obj.attr("rel")
    }, 
    function (r) {
        if(r.status) {
            $(data.rslt.obj).attr("id", "node_" + r.id);
        }
        else {
            $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
        }
    }
);
```

})

and for my add button

```
function Ajouter() {
    $('#jsmenu').jstree("create", null, "last",{ "attr" : { "rel" : "folder" } });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
$("#jsmenu").on("create_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    $("li#"+data.node.id).find("a").append(html);
});
```

`html` is a var containing your icons code.

Comment: Instead of using `.find("a")` you can directly do `$("li#" + data.node.id + " > a")`. I have no idea how much better it is performance-wise, though (it probably doesn't matter in most cases).
You can also directly find the anchor by id as Data Meister said.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the anchor directly by id:

`$("#jsmenu").on("create_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    $("#"+data.node.id+"_anchor").append(html);
});`